# Python, check type of object after circular import

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

Here are two files, foo.py and bar.py
bar.py has...

```
from foo import *
```

...at the top.  bar.py uses types defined n foo.

When importing bar.py from foo I am having trouble determining the types of objects.
Looking at the example below why do the calls to isinstance return False?
How can I check if these types are the same?

Thanks,

===== foo.py =====

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def funcA(self):
        print 'function a'
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Spam object %s' % repr(self.x)

class Eggs(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def funcB(self):
        print 'function b'
    def __str__(self):
        return "Eggs object (%s, %s, %s)" % (repr(self.x), repr(self.y), repr(self.z))

def main(fname):
    if not fname.endswith('.py'):
        raise Exception("Must be a .py file")
    module = __import__(fname[:-3])
    for item in module.DATA:
        if isinstance(item, Spam):
            item.funcA()
        elif isinstance(item, Eggs):
            item.funcB()
        print item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
        main(fname)
    sys.exit(0)
```

===== bar.py =====

```
from foo import *
DATA=[
Spam("hi"),
Spam("there"),
Eggs(1, 2, 3),
]
```

Comment: Can you show how you invoke this program, and what its output is?

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main('bar.py')
    sys.exit(0)
```

I got :

```
Spam object 'hi'
Spam object 'there'
Eggs object (1, 2, 3)
```

Move the **main** code and the main function to adifferent file and import foo and will work

```
#-- main.py --

import foo

def main(fname):
    if not fname.endswith('.py'):
        raise Exception("Must be a .py file")
    module = __import__(fname[:-3])
    for item in module.DATA:
        if isinstance(item, foo.Spam):
            item.funcA()
        elif isinstance(item, foo.Eggs):
            item.funcB()
        print item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main('bar.py')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Right... I want it to call funcA and funcB which would print other things

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing `Spam`, `Eggs` and the type of `item`?

```
Spam is <class '__main__.Spam'>
Eggs is <class '__main__.Eggs'>
type of item is <class 'foo.Spam'>
Spam object 'hi'
type of item is <class 'foo.Spam'>
Spam object 'there'
type of item is <class 'foo.Eggs'>
Eggs object (1, 2, 3)
```

The `foo.py` module is run twice, once as the main program and once when it's imported by `bar.py`.

In the main program, `Spam` and `Eggs` are defined as `__main__.Spam` and `__main__.Eggs`.

In an imported module, `Spam` and `Eggs` are defined as `foo.Spam` and `foo.Eggs`.

`__main__.Spam` != `foo.Spam`, `__main__.Eggs` != `foo.Eggs`.